# want to make panel visible depend upon condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

i tried

```
Visible='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(((Session["AccountId"].ToString()=="1")|| 
(Session["AccountID"].ToString()==""))?true:false) %>'
```

i want to make panel visible=true when session id=1 if not false..
above coding is not working any suggestion

Comment: Could you please define 'not working'? Do you get an error? What is the output of the <% ... %> part?

Comment: First you need to make sure what that Session["AccountId"] is displaying.

Comment: not working means here the panel is visible for both conditions

Comment: i want to make visible only for session["AccountId"]==1 not for empty session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take some care in formatting code.

You return true if the value is "1" or empty (""), which is in your case, always

You can use this:

```
Visible = '<%= Session["AccountId"].ToString()=="1"  %>'
```

This will write the result of the expression (which is a boolean value) as a string ("True" or "False"). And most probably this will work as well:

```
Visible = '<%= Session["AccountId"] == 1 %>'
```

Comment: Error 34 Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= Session["AccountId"] == 1 %>'

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried your one but the below one does work:

```
Visible='<%# (Session["AccountId"] ?? "").ToString() == "1" ? true : false%>'
```

Comment: That means that your session variable is wrong, can you please paste your complete aspx code for your panel as well as where you set your session variable?